# I can't hide the browser bar on TWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

if anyone can help me with my problem thank you, i will explain better.

I am trying to remove the browser bar from the top of my TWA, I have tried several things I read on the internet but so far nothing.
I already created the file "assetlinks.json" with my two fingerprints, both the app signature and the upload signature.

And yet the browser bar appears at the top of my application.

Here is the link to my "assetlinks.json":
https://app.planetspay.com.br/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Follow my application's link on Google Play:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.planetsplay.com.br

Here is my TWA-manifest.json file:

```
{
  "packageId": "app.planetsplay.com.br",
  "host": "app.planetspay.com.br",
  "name": "PlanetsPay",
  "launcherName": "PlanetsPay",
  "display": "standalone",
  "themeColor": "#16A591",
  "navigationColor": "#16A591",
  "navigationColorDark": "#16A591",
  "navigationDividerColor": "#16A591",
  "navigationDividerColorDark": "#16A591",
  "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "enableNotifications": true,
  "startUrl": "/logar?ref=twa",
  "iconUrl": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/img/icone-app.png",
  "splashScreenFadeOutDuration": 0,
  "signingKey": {
    "path": "F:\\RubensFlinco-PC\\Documents\\Github\\PlanetsPay-Aplicativo\\android.keystore",
    "alias": "android"
  },
  "appVersionName": "2",
  "appVersionCode": 2,
  "shortcuts": [
    {
      "name": "Meu QRCode",
      "shortName": "QRCode",
      "url": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/qrcode?twa=true&utm_source=shortcuts",
      "chosenIconUrl": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/img/icons/qrcode.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Emitir cobrança",
      "shortName": "Cobrar",
      "url": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/pessoal/cobrar?twa=true&utm_source=shortcuts",
      "chosenIconUrl": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/img/icons/cobrar.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Transferir dinheiro",
      "shortName": "Transferir",
      "url": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/pessoal/dinheiro/transferir?twa=true&utm_source=shortcuts",
      "chosenIconUrl": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/img/icons/transferir.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ver meu extrato",
      "shortName": "Extrato",
      "url": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/pessoal/extrato?twa=true&utm_source=shortcuts",
      "chosenIconUrl": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/img/icons/extrato.png"
    }
  ],
  "generatorApp": "bubblewrap-cli",
  "webManifestUrl": "https://app.planetspay.com.br/manifest.json",
  "fallbackType": "customtabs",
  "features": {},
  "alphaDependencies": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "enableSiteSettingsShortcut": false,
  "isChromeOSOnly": false,
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "fingerprints": [],
  "appVersion": "2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was my typo in the package name

Comment: What was it? And what should it be?